# Undefined variable: use_smtp error in php mail script

Tags: php, html, forms, email, nginx

I have a form on a webpage that calls a php script to send an email though it isn't working properly, my nginx error log gives the following when I submit the form;

```
2014/04/07 15:55:42 [error] 10829#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: use_smtp in /home/deployer/example/releases/20140407153701/form-handler.php on line 62" while reading response header from upstream, client:
86.131.120.178, server: example.net, request: "POST /form-handler.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.net", referrer: "http://example.net/"
```

line 62 is

> if($use_smtp == '1'){

from form-handler.php

```
$use_smtp = '0';
$emailto = 'me@example.net';

    // retrieve from parameters
    $emailfrom = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
    $nocomment = isset($_POST["nocomment"]) ? $_POST["nocomment"] : "";
    $subject = 'Apophenic Enquiry';
    $message = '';
    $response = '';
    $response_fail = 'There was an error verifying your details.';

        // Honeypot captcha
        if($nocomment == '') {

            $params = $_POST;
            foreach ( $params as $key=>$value ){

                if(!($key == 'ip' || $key == 'emailsubject' || $key == 'url' || $key == 'emailto' || $key == 'nocomment' || $key == 'v_error' || $key == 'v_email')){

                    $key = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $key));

                    if ( gettype( $value ) == "array" ){
                        $message .= "$key: \n";
                        foreach ( $value as $two_dim_value )
                        $message .= "...$two_dim_value<br>";
                    }else {
                        $message .= $value != '' ? "$key: $value\n" : '';
                    }
                }
            }

        $response = sendEmail($subject, $message, $emailto, $emailfrom);

        } else {

            $response = $response_fail;

        }

    echo $response;

// Run server-side validation
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {

    $from = $emailfrom;
    $response_sent = 'Thank you. Your messsage has been received.';
    $response_error = 'Error. Please try again.';
    $subject =  filter($subject);
    $url = "Origin Page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $ip = "IP Address: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $message = $content."\n$ip\r\n$url";

    // Validate return email & inform admin
    $emailto = filter($emailto);

    // Setup final message
    $body = wordwrap($message);

    if($use_smtp == '1'){

        $SmtpServer = 'SMTP SERVER';
        $SmtpPort = 'SMTP PORT';
        $SmtpUser = 'SMTP USER';
        $SmtpPass = 'SMTP PASSWORD';

        $to = $emailto;
        $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
        $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
        $response = $SMTPChat ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    } else {

        // Create header
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";

        // Send email
        $mail_sent = @mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $response = $mail_sent ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    }
    return $response;
}

// Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
function filter($value) {
    $pattern = array("/\n/", "/\r/", "/content-type:/i", "/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
    return $value;
}

exit;

?>
```

I don't know php so I've no idea what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

problem is with this line:

```
if($use_smtp == '1'){
```

Try to make $GLOBALS['user_smtp'] instead of $user_smtp or pass the value to function.

If you do not pass the variable to function PHP does not know about it because it is not inside.

I will try to explain it much better.

You have in first line of your code

```
$use_smtp = '0'
```

with this you create a variable name use_smtp and gives it string "0". (It's in main program).

Then you have a function "sendEmail". There you try to use this variable called "use_smtp" but for this function it does not exist because just "main" program know about it not the function. You have to neither write

```
$use_smtp = '0'
```

in function or pass it by variable like:

```
sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom, $use_smtp)
```

or change the line of code

```
if($use_smtp == '1'){
```

to

```
if($GLOBALS['use_smtp'] == '1'){
```

Comment: I have edited my previous post, I hope I wrote it much better now so you can understand it.